# nifi 1.8.0 fails to start webgui due to zip and jetty errors

Tags: kubernetes, zip, jetty, apache-nifi, redhat

I tried to build a docker image that starts nifi1.8.0 (yeah, it's an old version)
Here's the info in this image:
base OS: RH8

```
[root@dp-nifi-6c4cc6fdf5-n5psv logs]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.8 (Ootpa)
[root@dp-nifi-6c4cc6fdf5-n5psv logs]# uname -a
Linux dp-nifi-6c4cc6fdf5-n5psv 3.10.0-1160.90.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 17 08:39:44 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Java:

```
[root@dp-nifi-6c4cc6fdf5-n5psv logs]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_372"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_372-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.372-b07, mixed mode)
```

Nifi 1.8.0 is installed and started as root (can access all files)`enter code here`

```
# Install nifi 1.8.0 and nifi-toolkit 1.8.0
RUN curl --keepalive-time 3600 -ko /tmp/nifi-1.8.0-bin.tar.gz https://archive.apache.org/dist/nifi/1.8.0/nifi-1.8.0-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf /tmp/nifi-1.8.0-bin.tar.gz -C /tmp && \
    mv /tmp/nifi-1.8.0 /opt/nifi && \
    rm -f /tmp/nifi-1.8.0-bin.tar.gz && \
    curl --keepalive-time 3600 -ko /tmp/nifi-toolkit-1.8.0-bin.tar.gz https://archive.apache.org/dist/nifi/1.8.0//nifi-toolkit-1.8.0-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf /tmp/nifi-toolkit-1.8.0-bin.tar.gz -C /tmp && \
    mv -f /tmp/nifi-toolkit-1.8.0 /opt/nifi-toolkit && \
    rm -f /tmp/nifi-1.8.0-bin.tar.gz
```

However, when I start the container, I see two issues:

1. zip error:

2023-05-26 23:00:00,609 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker Unable to load NAR library bundles due to java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file Will proceed without loading any further Nar bundles

2. Jetty error: I assume it's related to zip error, dependency packages cannot be properly unzipped?

   2023-05-26 23:00:07,388 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.

   java.lang.NullPointerException: null

   at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.generate(DocGenerator.java:62)

   at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:841)

   at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.(NiFi.java:157)

   at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.(NiFi.java:71)

   at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:296)

   2023-05-26 23:00:07,389 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...

   2023-05-26 23:00:07,389 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).

Greatly appreciate if you can point to me what goes wrong.

Regards.

Comment: I bet you are missing `z` option for tar command.

Comment: @daggett it still does not work for me. without the z option, the nifi tar ball can be unzipped and untar-ed successfully anyway.

Comment: just check that after ungzip/untar *.nar files are zip archives. if not - you are unarchiving not correctly.

Comment: Thanks @daggett you are right, the error is caused not by the nifi tar ball but a few custom nars download failture (the nar is created but only with 401 unauthorized json error message. Once fixed, nifi can start successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @daggett you are right, the error is caused not by the nifi tar ball but a few custom nars download failture (the nar is created but only with 401 unauthorized json error message. Once fixed, nifi can start successfully.